# Asara Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ten?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yosef lived 110 years (Parshas Vayechi)

Yehoshua lived 110 years (Yehoshua 24, 29)

Shem died when Yitzchok was 110 years

Neis = 110

Parshas Ki Tzeitzei has 110 Pesukim

Answer (score 3):

The destruction of the first Beis Hamikdash, and the exile of the two remaining tribes, became inevitable 110 years before it happened. This was when Menashe (the most wicked of the Judean kings) ascended the throne and began to propagate idolatry and other major sins among the Jewish People.

(II Kings 21:10ff, 23:26-27, et al)

Answer (score 1):

According to [an opinion in the Ramban](http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_noach.html), the Flood waters were not falling but were "strengthening" for 110 days.